# How to get properties of an object stored in a List

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I retrieve data from a firebase realtime database which I then store into a List, so that I can display the data.

My Problem is, that the displayed data doesn't show the stored object with its properties, but the so called name/label or something simliar to this.

What is being displayed:

`com.example.husiapp2.Homework@1abbfc6`

What should be displayed (Object with properties):

```
Homework
-Title,
-Class
```

My code:

```
public class Homework {
    public String Title;
    public String Class;
    public String ExpireDate;

    public Homework(){}

    public Homework(String title, String aClass,String expireDate) {
        Title = title;
        Class = aClass;
        ExpireDate = expireDate;
    }

}
```

```
 DatabaseReference ref;
 Homework homework;
 final List<Homework> hw = new ArrayList<>();

 ListView hwlist;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_hw);
        Log.d("HWAC122",hw.toString());
        hwlist = findViewById(R.id.hwlist);
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Homework");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    homework = new Homework();
                    homework.Title = ds.getValue(Homework.class).Title;
                    homework.Class = ds.getValue(Homework.class).Class;
                    homework.ExpireDate = ds.getValue(Homework.class).ExpireDate;
                    Log.d("test123",homework.toString());
                    hw.add(homework);
                }
                SetAdapter();
            }


        });


    }
 public void SetAdapter(){
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Homework>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,hw);
        hwlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.example.husiapp2.Homework@1abbfc6` is the standard string format for objects that don't override `toString()`.  It's composed of the class of the object and its location in the JVM's memory.  If you want `toString()` to generate something else, you'll have to override it and make it return what you want to print.

```
public class Homework {
    public String Title;
    public String Class;
    public String ExpireDate;

    public Homework(){}

    public Homework(String title, String aClass,String expireDate) {
        Title = title;
        Class = aClass;
        ExpireDate = expireDate;
    }

    // Override toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Whatever you want it to be";
    }
}
```

It's not always best to override `toString()`.  Many times it's better to just write some other function, pass it the object, and have it return the formatted string. Either way, you'll have to write that code that generates the string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you're asking.  toString has nothing to do with anything called a "lifecycle".

Answer (score 0):

Implement getter and setter methods in java class which you have created. Press alt+insert and select implement getter and setter for all the variables which you have declared. Through this,you can insert data into firebase and retrieve data from firebase